# Issue with deployment polymer application to subdirectory

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a problem trying to deploy a polymer application to the server. I created the Application using Polymer-Cli. Also the routing is done using `<app-route>` element.
The server is IIS Server, and the issue comes because they want to deploy the application as a directory:

> rapidsites.com/msa/...
> I uploaded other websites to the root directory and I've never faced problems but in that case I had severals:

1. The application doesn't find my-app.html. (this one I solved by removing "/" from the begining in this way: `<link rel="import" href="src/my-app.html">`
2. The routing doesn't work all, the links miss the subdirectory and doesn't find anything.

This is the my-app element route:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}">
</app-route>
<iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name">
  <my-login name="login"></my-login>
  <my-workpanel name="workpanel" route="{{subroute}}"></my-workpanel>
</iron-pages>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue using the property use-hash-as-path in the app-location:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}">
</app-route>
```